# Dirichlet's 1842 Approximation theorem: Does this specific variant of the theorem actually exist?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, cryptography

From [this pdf](http://diamond.boisestate.edu/~liljanab/ISAS/course_materials/Iterated-WienerPresentation.pdf):

Theorem (Dirichle,1842)
Assume that $\gcd(a, b) = 1$. If $r,s$ are any natural numbers such
that $\gcd(r,s) = 1$, and $|\frac{a}{b} − \frac{r}{s}| < \frac{1}{2s^2}$ then $\frac{r}{s}$ is one of the convergents of $\frac{a}{b}$.

I presume they mean Dirichlet. I'm trying to figure out the proof for Wiener' theorem on attacking the RSA cryptosystem and it would make my life a lot easier if this other theorem actually exists and is referable but I can't find this specific variant anywhere. Does it actually exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is Legendre's theorem in Diophantine approximations. See e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/531736/legendres-proof-continued-fractions-from-hardys-book). An extension, which also has applications on Wiener's type attacks on RSA and other similar cryptosystems can be found [in this paper](https://web.math.pmf.unizg.hr/~duje/pdf/rsa.pdf).